# arm c code disasembly confusing,

Tags: arm, inline-assembly

I have below the code:

```
    struct inner{
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
};

struct outer{
    struct inner *in;
};

void test_func(struct outer *o)
{
    printh(o->in->b);
}
```

printh simple displays the value in hexformat.
The code is complied with the following flags -DSMP -marm -mcpu=cortex-a15

The assembly generated is as follows:

```
f0001cc0 <test_func>:
f0001cc0:       e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
f0001cc4:       e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
f0001cc8:       e24dd008        sub     sp, sp, #8
f0001ccc:       e50b0008        str     r0, [fp, #-8]
f0001cd0:       e51b3008        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
f0001cd4:       e5933000        ldr     r3, [r3]
f0001cd8:       e5933004        ldr     r3, [r3, #4]
f0001cdc:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
f0001ce0:       ebfffb04        bl      f00008f8 <printh>
f0001ce4:       e24bd004        sub     sp, fp, #4
f0001ce8:       e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}
```

With this code I get a data abort on f0001cd8 as r3 was loaded 0 in f0001cd4. But r3 was loaded with the address of o correctly in f0001cd4. 
All I have is a simple line. I dont seem to understand why the following instruction is generated

```
f0001cd4:       e5933000        ldr     r3, [r3]
```

Because of this I am getting a data abort.

Comment: `ldr     r3, [r3]` loads the `in` pointer into `r3`, and the next line uses that pointer to get `in->b`. You haven't shown us how you set up the struct that you pass to `test_func`, which makes it difficult to say what the problem is.

Comment: Are you sure you allocated memory for both `inner` and `outer` ?

Comment: @PaulR That must be it, memory access violation.

Answer (score 0):

```
f0001cc0 <test_func>:
f0001cc0:       e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}           ;\
f0001cc4:       e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4         ;> create stack frame
f0001cc8:       e24dd008        sub     sp, sp, #8         ;/
f0001ccc:       e50b0008        str     r0, [fp, #-8]      ; save first arg (o) in stack
f0001cd0:       e51b3008        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]      ; load o
f0001cd4:       e5933000        ldr     r3, [r3]           ; load o->in
f0001cd8:       e5933004        ldr     r3, [r3, #4]       ; load o->in->b
f0001cdc:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3             ; use as first arg to next fn
f0001ce0:       ebfffb04        bl      f00008f8 <printh>  ; call printh
f0001ce4:       e24bd004        sub     sp, fp, #4         ;\
f0001ce8:       e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}           ;/ destroy stack frame
```

The above (obviously compiled with no optimization) code is first loading `o->in`, and then `o->in->b`. `o->in` comes up at 0, which means that you haven't allocated memory for it.